# json.loads() decodes only with raw string literal

Tags: python, json

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
str_2_load='{"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" \u003eTwitter \u003c\/a\u003e"}'
json.loads(str_2_load)
```

Getting the following error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 26 (char 25)

But if I use the raw string literal, it works fine.
i.e.

```
str_2_load=r'{"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" \u003eTwitter \u003c\/a\u003e"}'
json.loads(str_2_load)
```

Since the `str_2_load` is dynamically assigned, I am looking for a fix for the above issue.

Comment: If it was dynamically assigned then you shouldn't see this problem. Show your real code.

Answer (score -1):

replace all '\' with '\\':

```
>>> str_2_load='{"source":"\\u003ca href=\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\" \\u003eTwitter    \\u003c\\/a\\u003e"}'
>>> json.loads(str_2_load)
{u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com" >Twitter </a>'}
```

Comment: Better: use the `r` modifier so all backslashes in the string will be taken literally, then you don't have to double them all up: `str_2_load='{"source":r"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" \u003eTwitter \u003c\/a\u003e"}'`

Comment: @rmunn absolutely, but he seemed to be resistant to doing so

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes, but until he gives us more information, the only thing we can do is point out the errors in the code as it stands.

Comment: @rmunn, in a deeply nested JSON with sporadic raw text, what is the regex to automatically replace raw strings, eg: `' AU : \\xA0'` dict of `char:ord(char)` = {' ': 32, 'A': 65, 'U': 85, ':': 58, '\\': 92, 'x': 120, '0': 48} can be replaced with `.replace(r'\xA0', '\xA0'). what's the general pattern ?

Comment: @alancalvitti - That's way too complex a question to answer in comments to a six-year-old question. Ask that in a new question and give a proper example of what you need, then you'll get much better responses (since everyone will see it, not just me).

Answer (score -2):

I believe if you make str_2_load a raw string by adding a 'r' in the beginning of the string. Somehow this is related to the regex.

```
str_2_load=r'{"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" \u003eTwitter \u003c\/a\u003e"}'
json.loads(str_2_load)

#output {'source': '<a href="http://twitter.com" >Twitter </a>'}
```